# Master theorem problem

Tags: computer-science, infinitesimals

Let $$T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2}) + \frac{n}{\log(n)}$$
Canno't be solved using the master theorem, and $$T(n) = 4T(\frac{n}{2}) + \frac{n}{\log(n)}$$
Can be solved. Why is that?

Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)

Comment: Why do you think? What case would this recurrence relation fall into in your opinion? Why?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "why is that?". The Master Theorem can not be applied here, because this case does not follow the requirements of any case in the Master Theorem.

Comment: @an4s The first equation falls due to the difference being non-polynomial. The second instance however seems to me like case 1 of the theorem, but I can't seem to prove it without reaching the same conclusion as the first equation.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker I'm asking why is the second one possible, if the first isn't.

Comment: Because $$\exists\epsilon > 0\ \ s.t\ \ f(n)= O(n^{\log_2(4)-\epsilon})$$ But $$\not\exists\epsilon > 0\ \ s.t\ \ f(n)=O( n^{\log_2(2)-\epsilon})$$

Comment: @TheHolyJoker Thanks!